# Group by with MAX in SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to retrieve the max(CRN) with a group by function to retrieve duplicate records aside from CRN but it is not working:
below is my select statement:

```
    select max(CRN), TERM, SUBJECT, COURSE, SCH, R_KEY, R_PERC 
    from database 
     group by        TERM, SUBJECT, COURSE, SCH, R_KEY, R_PERC
```

Below is my input file:

```
CRN  TERM   SUBJECT COURSE  SCH   R_KEY R_PERC
10607      10   DGRG    230  K  36714   37
10607      10   DGRG    230  K  36715   38
11658      10   MATH    101  E  213162  100
11658      10   MATH    101  L  182471  100
12811      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50
12811      10   MHRM    310  L  130923  50
12879      10   MHRM    310  L  32738   50
12879      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50
12912      10   MHRM    310  L  120641  50
12912      10   MHRM    310  L  121008  50
```

I am expecting the same below output as (above input) because I have  different "R_PERC" or "R_KEY":

```
CRN  TERM   SUBJECT COURSE  SCH   R_KEY R_PERC
10607      10   DGRG    230  K  36714   37
10607      10   DGRG    230  K  36715   38
11658      10   MATH    101  E  213162  100
11658      10   MATH    101  L  182471  100
12811      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50
12811      10   MHRM    310  L  130923  50
12879      10   MHRM    310  L  32738   50
12879      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50
12912      10   MHRM    310  L  120641  50
12912      10   MHRM    310  L  121008  50
```

But my actual output is only one record for **CRN 12811** as below, noting that the output would be similar for all CRNs (meaning one record only) if we include above input file in a much bigger file record:

```
CRN  TERM   SUBJECT COURSE  SCH   R_KEY R_PERC
10607      10   DGRG    230  K  36714   37
10607      10   DGRG    230  K  36715   38
11658      10   MATH    101  E  213162  100
11658      10   MATH    101  L  182471  100
12811      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50

12879      10   MHRM    310  L  32738   50
12879      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50
12912      10   MHRM    310  L  120641  50
12912      10   MHRM    310  L  121008  50
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: A table named database... Very confusing.

Comment: It is Oracle databse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the count:

```
+----------+----------+------+---------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| max(CRN) | count(*) | TERM | SUBJECT | COURSE | SCH  | R_KEY  | R_PERC |
+----------+----------+------+---------+--------+------+--------+--------+
|    10607 |        1 |   10 | DGRG    |    230 | K    |  36714 |     37 |
|    10607 |        1 |   10 | DGRG    |    230 | K    |  36715 |     38 |
|    11658 |        1 |   10 | MATH    |    101 | E    | 213162 |    100 |
|    11658 |        1 |   10 | MATH    |    101 | L    | 182471 |    100 |
|    12879 |        1 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    |  32738 |     50 |
|    12879 |        2 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    |  32951 |     50 | <-- your 12811 record is included in here, because both records have the same R_KEY
|    12912 |        1 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    | 120641 |     50 |
|    12912 |        1 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    | 121008 |     50 |
|    12811 |        1 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    | 130923 |     50 |
+----------+----------+------+---------+--------+------+--------+--------+
```

These two records get grouped:

```
+-------+------+---------+--------+------+-------+--------+
| CRN   | TERM | SUBJECT | COURSE | SCH  | R_KEY | R_PERC |
+-------+------+---------+--------+------+-------+--------+
| 12811 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    | 32951 |     50 |
| 12879 |   10 | MHRM    |    310 | L    | 32951 |     50 |
+-------+------+---------+--------+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks but why Oracle database or MySQL database are reacting that way; meaning deleting some records that are not duplicated ??

Comment: They are not deleted. Look at the second table I included. They are grouped and displayed as one row, because you haven't included CRN in the group by. 12879 is greater than 12811, so this is displayed since you're using max() function. The behaviour is totally fine and correct and expected.

Comment: but why the following record disappeared:

Comment: 12811      10   MHRM    310  L  130923  50  instead of                12811      10   MHRM    310  L  32951   50

Comment: What do you mean with "disappeared"? The record `12811 10 MHRM 310 L 130923 50` is right there, the record `12811 10 MHRM 310 L 32951 50` is like I said in the group with `12879 10 MHRM 310 L 32951 50`, as you can tell by the count column.

Comment: yes but record "12811 10 MHRM 310 L 130923 50" is disappearing; please check my third output list in the question above at the first beginning

Comment: Can you recheck? I can not reproduce that. For me it's there. See here for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60ada/2/0 I can't reproduce it in MySQL either. Record is there.